# make new data set which is based on number of observations by years in each group

Tags: r

```
    firm year     inv   value capital
1      1 1935  317.60 3078.50    2.80
2      1 1936  391.80 4661.70   52.60
3      1 1937  410.60 5387.10  156.90
4      1 1938  257.70 2792.20  209.20
5      1 1939  330.80 4313.20  203.40
6      1 1940  461.20 4643.90  207.20
7      1 1941  512.00 4551.20  255.20
8      1 1942  448.00 3244.10  303.70
9      2 1936  355.30 1807.10   50.50
10     2 1937  469.90 2676.30  118.10
11     2 1938  262.30 1801.90  260.20
12     3 1935   33.10 1170.60   97.80
13     4 1935   40.29  417.50   10.50
14     4 1936   72.76  837.80   10.20
15     4 1937   66.26  883.90   34.70
16     4 1938   51.60  437.90   51.80
17     4 1939   52.41  679.70   64.30
```

I want to make new data set which includes each company have observations at least 4 for years because I will use 1~4 lags in regression.
In this case, firm 1 and 4 are for new data set and firm 2 and 3 should be removed.

How can I use subset command and make new data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N >= 4L], firm]
#     firm year    inv  value capital
#  1:    1 1935 317.60 3078.5     2.8
#  2:    1 1936 391.80 4661.7    52.6
#  3:    1 1937 410.60 5387.1   156.9
#  4:    1 1938 257.70 2792.2   209.2
#  5:    1 1939 330.80 4313.2   203.4
#  6:    1 1940 461.20 4643.9   207.2
#  7:    1 1941 512.00 4551.2   255.2
#  8:    1 1942 448.00 3244.1   303.7
#  9:    4 1935  40.29  417.5    10.5
# 10:    4 1936  72.76  837.8    10.2
# 11:    4 1937  66.26  883.9    34.7
# 12:    4 1938  51.60  437.9    51.8
# 13:    4 1939  52.41  679.7    64.3
```

For big data sets binary search could be useful

```
setkey(setDT(df)[, indx := .N >= 4L, firm], indx)[J(TRUE)]
```

Or maybe just

```
setDT(df)[df[, indx := .N >= 4L, firm]$indx]
```

Or (as pointed out by @Arun)- this seems the best one

```
setDT(df)[, if(.N >= 4L) .SD, by = firm]
```

Comment: Also `setDT(df)[, if(.N >= 4L) .SD, by=firm]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to subset all those firms with 4 or more observations, you can do it like this:

```
df[ave(df$firm, df$firm, FUN = length) >= 4,]
#   firm year    inv  value capital
#1     1 1935 317.60 3078.5     2.8
#2     1 1936 391.80 4661.7    52.6
#3     1 1937 410.60 5387.1   156.9
#4     1 1938 257.70 2792.2   209.2
#5     1 1939 330.80 4313.2   203.4
#6     1 1940 461.20 4643.9   207.2
#7     1 1941 512.00 4551.2   255.2
#8     1 1942 448.00 3244.1   303.7
#13    4 1935  40.29  417.5    10.5
#14    4 1936  72.76  837.8    10.2
#15    4 1937  66.26  883.9    34.7
#16    4 1938  51.60  437.9    51.8
#17    4 1939  52.41  679.7    64.3
```

Or using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, firm) %>% filter(n() >= 4)
```

Comment: Nice side-by-side with Andrie's example to illustrate the `n` function in dplyr. I wonder if `dplyr::n` can keep up with `table` in multi-dimensional gymnastics?

Comment: @BondedDust, do you mean when operating on e.g. 3 or more dimensional arrays? (I wouldn't expect dplyr to work with that but maybe I misunderstood your comment?)

Comment: That's what I meant. But I'm not a savvy dplyr-user and maybe `group_by` can handle multiple strata-conditions?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what a strata condition is.. My understanding is that dplyr only works with data.frame-like objects which is why I don't think it would work with multi-dimensional arrays (but that may be wrong). dplyr's n() will obviously not replace table() but it never intended to do so, I believe.

Comment: Look at the help page for `group_by`. It does accept an arbitrary length set of "variables to group by" which is what I meant.

Comment: Yes, but those variables to group by only refer to data.frame like objects or "tbls". Would be interesting if you could post an example case of what you mean.

Comment: After I used this command "group_by(df, firm) %>% filter(n() >= 4)" I got error message as follows: Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @yoshi,you have to install the package dplyr first and then load it into your library.

Comment: @beginneR Perhaps `group_size(group_by(df, firm, year %/% 2))` to cross classify by firm and 2 year interval.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `table()` and simple subsetting:

```
z <- table(dat$firm)
idx <- names(z)[z>=4]

with(dat, dat[firm %in% idx, ])
```

The result:

```
   firm year    inv  value capital
1     1 1935 317.60 3078.5     2.8
2     1 1936 391.80 4661.7    52.6
3     1 1937 410.60 5387.1   156.9
4     1 1938 257.70 2792.2   209.2
5     1 1939 330.80 4313.2   203.4
6     1 1940 461.20 4643.9   207.2
7     1 1941 512.00 4551.2   255.2
8     1 1942 448.00 3244.1   303.7
13    4 1935  40.29  417.5    10.5
14    4 1936  72.76  837.8    10.2
15    4 1937  66.26  883.9    34.7
16    4 1938  51.60  437.9    51.8
17    4 1939  52.41  679.7    64.3
```

---

PS. To recreate the data from the question:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" firm year     inv   value capital
1      1 1935  317.60 3078.50    2.80
2      1 1936  391.80 4661.70   52.60
3      1 1937  410.60 5387.10  156.90
4      1 1938  257.70 2792.20  209.20
5      1 1939  330.80 4313.20  203.40
6      1 1940  461.20 4643.90  207.20
7      1 1941  512.00 4551.20  255.20
8      1 1942  448.00 3244.10  303.70
9      2 1936  355.30 1807.10   50.50
10     2 1937  469.90 2676.30  118.10
11     2 1938  262.30 1801.90  260.20
12     3 1935   33.10 1170.60   97.80
13     4 1935   40.29  417.50   10.50
14     4 1936   72.76  837.80   10.20
15     4 1937   66.26  883.90   34.70
16     4 1938   51.60  437.90   51.80
17     4 1939   52.41  679.70   64.30")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that format, but it needs time to practice for me. I will post the proper data format at the next time.