# Make subset which is chopped off first 4 observations by each group

Tags: r

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" firm year     inv   value capital
1      1 1935  317.60 3078.50    2.80
2      1 1936  391.80 4661.70   52.60
3      1 1937  410.60 5387.10  156.90
4      1 1938  257.70 2792.20  209.20
5      1 1939  330.80 4313.20  203.40
6      1 1940  461.20 4643.90  207.20
7      1 1941  512.00 4551.20  255.20
8      1 1942  448.00 3244.10  303.70
9      2 1936  355.30 1807.10   50.50
10     2 1937  469.90 2676.30  118.10
11     2 1938  262.30 1801.90  260.20
12     3 1935   33.10 1170.60   97.80
13     4 1935   40.29  417.50   10.50
14     4 1936   72.76  837.80   10.20
15     4 1937   66.26  883.90   34.70
16     4 1938   51.60  437.90   51.80
17     4 1939   52.41  679.70   64.30")
```

I used the same data set for other question yesterday. Now after making new data set ( the new data set includes only firm 1 and 4, because those firms include more than 4 observation), I want to remove 4 observations for each firms. 
In this case, firm 1 has 4 observations (1939, 1940,1941,1942 ) and firm 4 has 1 observation(1939).

For time series data, we can use "window" command for getting observations for certain years. However, for panel data set, how can I handle for time (year, month, quarter), especially unbalanced panel data set?

Comment: This question is similar to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236828/make-new-data-set-which-is-based-on-number-of-observations-by-years-in-each-grou) where you got several answers but never accepted any of them. Click the green check mark next to the answer you found most helpful or used in your code.

Comment: @beginneR I didn't use this site before, so I didn't know that I should accept the answer. where is the the green check mark? and what is the >%> ? Thanks.

Comment: No Problem, that's why I'm telling you this. The %>% operator is used to chain several operations together. Here, it's used in the dplyr code and you can use it after installing and loading the package.

Comment: @beginneR Did i choose the previous answer?-- It means that I didn't find green check box and I clicked the "votes" box.

Comment: What do you mean? (If you want to know whether you accepted an answer to your previous question: not yeat, as far as I can see. Once you check an answer you'll see the green check mark beside it). The check box is below the upvote/downvote buttons. It turns green once you click it.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to `chop off` first 4 observations after subsetting the dataset,

```
indx <- with(df, ave(seq_along(firm), firm, FUN=length)>=4)
df1 <- df[indx,]
df1[with(df1, ave(seq_along(firm), firm,  FUN=seq_along)>4),]
#     firm year    inv  value capital
#5     1 1939 330.80 4313.2   203.4
#6     1 1940 461.20 4643.9   207.2
#7     1 1941 512.00 4551.2   255.2
#8     1 1942 448.00 3244.1   303.7
#17    4 1939  52.41  679.7    64.3
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N>=4], by=firm]$V1][, tail(.SD,-4), by=firm]
 #     firm year    inv  value capital
 #1:    1 1939 330.80 4313.2   203.4
 #2:    1 1940 461.20 4643.9   207.2
 #3:    1 1941 512.00 4551.2   255.2
 #4:    1 1942 448.00 3244.1   303.7
 #5:    4 1939  52.41  679.7    64.3
```

Or

```
 setDT(df)[,.SD[.N>=4 & (1:.N >4)], by=firm]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
     group_by(firm) %>% 
     filter(n()>=4) %>% 
     slice(-(1:4))
 #     firm year    inv  value capital
 #1    1 1939 330.80 4313.2   203.4
 #2    1 1940 461.20 4643.9   207.2
 #3    1 1941 512.00 4551.2   255.2
 #4    1 1942 448.00 3244.1   303.7
 #5    4 1939  52.41  679.7    64.3
```

Or another option in `dplyr` (contributed by @beginneR)

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(firm) %>% 
    filter(n()>=4 & 1:n() > 4)
```

Comment: Another dplyr option would be `df %>% group_by(firm) %>% filter(n()>=4 & 1:n() > 4)` (or using `row_number()` instead of `1:n()`).